# AcquireToken async returning same token before expiry time

Tags: azure, oauth, token, azure-active-directory

I have registered my application with Azure AD App registration.

In my scenario i am using Azure Adal AquireTokenAsync method with client credentials which is always returning same token.

i need a new token for every user session.

for testing purpose i have created console application to test the behaviour.

```
string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"], 
      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"]);

        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppKey"]);
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        int retryCount = 0;
        bool retry = false;
        retry = false;
        try
        {
            result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ResourceId"], clientCredential);
            result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ResourceId"], clientCredential);
        }
        catch (AdalException ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            authContext = null;
        }
```

In both the calls it is returning the same token.

however for every fresh execution it is returning new token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADAL context cache keep token.If you need to get it refreshed please clear the cache using

```
  authContext.TokenCache.Clear();
```

it will clear the cache.

Answer (score 1):

It's because inside `AuthenticationContext`, there is `TokenCache` to cache the `id_token`. So, if you would like to have new token every time calling  `AcquireTokenAsync`, set `TokenCache` is null when creating `AuthenticationContext` object:

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false, null);
```

Please prefer [the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_AuthenticationContext__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_TokenCache_)